# Why do some users vanish and turn into user...?

Tags: support, user-accounts

A user recently disappeared out of nowhere. I flagged them as a kid a while ago. Do people appear like this when their account has been deleted?

Comment: Yup, account deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, usernames revert to the default 'userXXXX' username when an account is deleted.

Users can be deleted for a variety of reasons. To go into specifics why particular user(s) were deleted would be a violation of the privacy of that user.